# nginx bind failed

Tags: 13.04, nginx, aws

when I run nginx, I get error,

nginx is started from npm run scripts

I had run npm run start-prod
scripts:
start-prod: has the following command

```
 concurrently --no-color "uwsgi --ini build/docker/uwsgi.ini" "nginx"  "npm run render-prod"
```

npm run render-prod value for script is  "render-prod": "babel-node node/react-render.jsx"

```
ntdl@1.0.2 start-prod /home/ubuntu/bharath/sourcecode/projects/NTDL/ntdl
> concurrently --no-color "uwsgi --ini build/docker/uwsgi.ini" "nginx"  "npm run render-prod"    
[0] [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from build/docker/uwsgi.ini    
[0] *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Wed Feb 14 01:10:08 2018] ***    
[0] compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 09 February 2018 02:01:25    
[0] os: Linux-4.4.0-1049-aws #58-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 12 23:17:09 UTC 2018    
[0] nodename: ip-10-254-3-58
[0] machine: x86_64        
[0] clock source: unix            
[0] pcre jit disabled    
[0] detected number of CPU cores: 8    
[0] current working directory: 
/home/ubuntu/bharath/sourcecode/projects/NTDL/ntdl    
[0] writing pidfile to 
/home/ubuntu/bharath/sourcecode/projects/NTDL/ntdl/build/docker/ntdl.pid    
[0] detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi    
[0] setgid() to 33    
[0] setuid() to 33    
[0] chdir() to /home/ubuntu/bharath/sourcecode/projects/NTDL/ntdl    
[0] your processes number limit is 60090    
[0] your memory page size is 4096 bytes    
[0] detected max file descriptor number: 1048576    
[0] lock engine: pthread robust mutexes    
[0] thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)    
[0] bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]    
[1] nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored    
[1] nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)    
[0] uwsgi --ini build/docker/uwsgi.ini exited with code 1
[2]    
[2] > ntdl@1.0.2 render-prod /home/ubuntu/bharath/sourcecode/projects/NTDL/ntdl    
[2] > babel-node node/react-render.jsx    
[2]    
[1] nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)    
[1] nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)    
[1] nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[2] React render server listening at http://0.0.0.0:9009
[1] nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[1] nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
[1] nginx exited with code 1
```

Please help me in fixing this nginx bind error.

TIA,

Kind Regards,
Bharath AK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other process is already listening on port 80.  This may mean, for example, that you have an Apache process running already.

You can use this suggested command to find out what may be listening on that port:

```
sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN
```

Note: In rare cases it could be that a separate nginx is already listening on the port, for example if you manually started an nginx daemon (not recommended) or if you've modified which user nginx runs under (not recommended).  More than likely, however, it'll be some other application listening on that port.

Ubuntu lets you install two web servers at once, since it's possible to configure them to listen on different ports.  If you don't do this, you'll have problems with one or the other starting.

Comment: Hi thomasrutter,  thanks for your reply.  I am able to progress with your idea.      now I am able to run the npm and sock file is created by uwsgi for nginx to intereact with it.  But still I get nginx exited with code 0,  I am not able to find why.  secondly I am using aws ubuntu, how will i see it in the browser, do I have to any settings in nginx.conf.  Do I have provide proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host "54.206.154.95" like this  to see in browser.  I am not able to see in browser i dont know what is blocking  please help me with many thanks Bharath AK

Answer (score 0):

As @thomasrutter said, Check the port using `sudo lsof -i -P -n` and check where the `port 80` is used. If that process is not required, kill that process and check `nginx` configuration again with `sudo nginx -t`. Another thing is you want to check your page on the browser, then after running your page you can either edit the server block in `nginx.conf` or `sites-available/default` block where you can proxy pass your page `address:port` to `port 80` so that you have to just hit the public IP address of your port, and then you can see that page on the browser.

Comment: Hello. Very confusing answer. First referring to another person is not a good idea. How is anyone going to see that it could be gone. Second your second thing is just plain confusing.

Comment: Hey, @David sorry for the inconvenience. Did not want to confuse anyone, just want to help him. I just need to say in the 2nd part of my suggestion, If port 80 of his server is being used then he can either stop that process or change that processes port so that port 80 which is the default HTTP port will be free to use.

Comment: Hello, please see the formatting guidelines here: meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/…. Also, if part of your answer uses another answer to resolve the issue, then you should include that content in your answer. Only **complete** answers should be entered. Alternatively you can add it as a comment to the answer that contains the other information. This helps to ensure that uses aren't directed to a number of 'half answers' and are able to separate the music from the noise. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @theYnot Thanks for the help and the guidance.

Comment: You're welcome @J0nty